# Discord Bot Authorizing with server (headers)

Tags: python, http-headers, discord.py

I'm attempting to authenticate and post information regarding my bot to a server that lists them.  The api states that I must authenticate with their server first by sending an authentication token for my bot.  I've managed to get this to work.  However, when I then attempt to POST the information to the URL specified, I don't even receive a response code.

```
async def apiPost():
    servers = list(client.servers)
    numServers = len(client.servers)    

    URL = "https://www.discordbotlist.com"

    URL2 = "https://www.discordbotlist.com/api/bots/:botIDOmitted/stats"

    servdata = {'guilds':int(numServers)}

    authorization = {'Authorization':'Bot realTokenOmitted'}

    r=requests.get(URL,headers=authorization)
    print(r)
    r=requests.post(URL2, data=servdata)
    print(r)
```

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong at this point.

Comment: Does this api send any cookies? If so, you need to use requests session for further communication. [src](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/)

Comment: Honestly I'm not quite positive... their API documentation isn't the most understandable:  https://discordbotlist.com/api-docs

Comment: Aha! As i can see you need to add ```{'Authorization':'Bot realTokenOmitted'}``` to all your requests you're doing. So add ```headers=authorization``` to each request :)

Comment: Attempted, received a 200 response for the `r=requests.get(URL,headers=authorization)` but received a 404 response code when I attempt to do `r=requests.post(URL2,headers=authorization,data=servdata)`

Comment: Because your URL is "https://www.discordbotlist.com/api/bots/:botIDOmitted/stats" and you need to set ```:botIDOmitted``` with your ID!

Comment: I have, I just omitted the ID for this post.

Comment: No you havent! Your URL should look like ```https://www.discordbotlist.com/api/bots/abcdef123/stats```.

Comment: I understand this, in the code I specified in this stackoverflow post, I omitted the ID from the URL, however, In the code I'm running, I am including the correct ID.

Comment: 404 means Not Found. Strange.

Comment: I got it to authenticate and post correctly.  I think the issue was that the API documentation was telling me to post to `"https://www.discordbotlist.com/api/bots/:botIDOmitted/stats"` and I actually needed to omit the `:` and post to `"https://www.discordbotlist.com/api/bots/botIDOmitted/stats"` instead.

Comment: No, :botIDOmitted is a placeholder for your ID. #API Documentation failed. :)

Comment: Many docs use `:` in :var to state the variable type of the expression. I don't think it would be interesting to use `:123456` to index values.